# Increase in the size of a container

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

A cylindrical metal rod of length $L_0$ is shaped into a ring with a small gap as shown. On heating the system it is given that $x, r$ and $d$ increase.

[image: Heated ring]

I am unable to figure out why would $x$ also necessarily increase. Obviously $r$ and $d$ are part of the same container so that would increase at the same rate. But it is not given that $x$ is made of the same material as the container. I am not saying that the rod wouldn’t increase at all. It would, because it is made of metal. But isn’t it possible that the rod increases in length only? How can we determine that its width also increases ?

Comment: For practical uses, see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrink-fitting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All dimensions of the object change with temperature. Nature doesn't know what we call length. With growing temperature all atoms of the object move further apart an the object expands. Unless the object is made of unisotropic material all dimensions have the same percentual change.

Now for the $x$. Imagine having a full ring of metal. Upon heating its diameter grows. If you marked a segment $x$ it would also grow. Now if you cut out the segment $x$ the gap will grow because all the dimensions increase the same.

To picture this take pencil and draw square 5x5 on a squared paper. Take rubber and make a gap in the square. Now redraw your square with gap increasing all dimensions twice. What is the result? Is the gap wider?

Comment: Ohh ! Thanks for the analogy. The gap would increase, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

If an unconstrained body of a uniform material is heated and experiences thermal expansion, all linear dimensions of the body expand by the same fraction in all directions. If you assume that all linear dimensions of the rod expand equally, then the new shape must be geometrically similar to the original shape.  This is satisfied if the gap x also expands.  To keep the gap x from not expanding by the same fraction, you would have to exert forces on the ring to constrain the gap, and the thermal expansion of the body would not then be unconstrained.